# Query using condition within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models, user and centre, which have a many to many relationship.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :centres 
end

class Centre < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :centre_id, :city_id, :state_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
end
```

Now I have an user with multiple centres, and I want to retrieve all the centres that have the same "state_id" as that user.

This is what I am doing now

```
state_id_array = []
user.centres.each do |centre|
  state_id_array << centre.state_id
end
return Centre.where("state_id IN (?)", state_id_array).uniq
```

It works, but it's very ugly. Is there a better way for achieving this? Ideally a one line query.

> UPDATE

Now I have

```
Centre.where('centres.state_id IN (?)', Centre.select('state_id').joins(:user).where('users.id=(?)', user))
```

The subquery work by itself, but when I tried to execute the entire query, I get NULL for the inner query.

```
Centre.select('state_id').joins(:user).where('users.id=(?)', user)
```

will generate

```
 SELECT state_id FROM "centres" INNER JOIN "centres_users" ON "centres_users"."centre_id" = "centres"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "centres_users"."user_id" WHERE (users.id = (5))
```

Which return 'SA', 'VIC', 'VIC'

but the whole query will generate

```
 SELECT DISTINCT "centres".* FROM "centres" WHERE (centres.state_id IN (NULL,NULL,NULL))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
.select(:state_id)
```

will retrieve a model with only the state_id column populated. To retrieve a field, use

```
.pluck(:state_id)
```

Below is the final query I had

```
Centre.where('centres.state_id IN (?)', Centre.joins(:user).where('users.id=(?)', user).pluck('state_id').uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does user also has state_id column if yes then try this,
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.state_id = centers.state_id")
else
try User.joins(:center)

Comment: no... user can have multiple centres (multiple state)